# Trying to Packstack. Don't have Extras

Tags: centos7, yum, openstack

So I want to Pack-stack. Proof of concept cloud.
Following this guide https://www.rdoproject.org/install/packstack/

Build for Centos 7. I have this.

```
[root@tbgn ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
```

So I run the install.

```
[root@tbgn ~]# yum install -y centos-release-openstack-rocky
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirrors.ovh.net
 * centosplus: mirror.centos.org
 * epel: ewr.edge.kernel.org
 * ius: archive.linux.duke.edu
 * updates: centos.mirrors.ovh.net
No package centos-release-openstack-rocky available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Couldn't find the package. Doc said I need extras. Says to use subscription-manager.

`-bash: subscription-manager: command not found`

Okay. Asked around. Coworker says I need extras.

```
[root@tbgn ~]# yum repolist all | grep extra
C7.0.1406-extras/x86_64         CentOS-7.0.1406 - Extras         disabled
C7.1.1503-extras/x86_64         CentOS-7.1.1503 - Extras         disabled
C7.2.1511-extras/x86_64         CentOS-7.2.1511 - Extras         disabled
C7.3.1611-extras/x86_64         CentOS-7.3.1611 - Extras         disabled
C7.4.1708-extras/x86_64         CentOS-7.4.1708 - Extras         disabled
!extras/7/x86_64                CentOS-7 - Plus                  disabled
extras-source/7                 CentOS-7 - Extras Sources        disabled
```

I only have plus. It's disabled. Enabled plus. Same issue.

How do I get extras?

Comment: Where did you get CentOS from? This is not the expected output from a system installed from genuine CentOS media. Inspect all of the yum repo files, and you may find a clue.

Comment: My CentOS came from OVH Hosting. This was the Centos 7 install they had bundled in their control panel for dedicated servers. What do I look for in my inspection/how would I other than looking over "yum repolist all"?

Comment: Hmm. With OVH I always suggest you ignore their installation, and use the IPMI console to install the OS yourself. Their installer makes very questionable choices in setting up things like filesystem, RAID, etc. Apparently they are also doing something odd to the OS itself.

Comment: Awh man. I already got a few users renting space on the thing. Alright. I've never done that before though. Do you have steps/a guide I can follow on doing this? I've never even heard of the term "IPMI console" before.

Comment: Click "From a Java applet (KVM)" and you'll get the console of your dedicated server.

Comment: $240 to enable that under IPMI.... Any other options? Can I somehow add it?

Comment: $240? really? Just what OVH service do you have? That's far more than I pay for any server and I get it for free with all of them!

Comment: Yeah its really weird.. "The IPMI module is not available on this server. However, you can use a KVM to benefit from this feature." On my MC-32 I have access to this. But with their MC-64 plan it just isn't letting me. -- I did some backtracking. Looks like I followed this guide in oct or so in an attempt to install rdiff-backup via extras. Ultimentally didn't work but do you think this has anything to do with it? https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-rhel-centos-6-5/

Comment: You might want to open a ticket with OVH because that's not supposed to be something you are charged for.

Comment: Called them up...they said since mine is overclocked it's not included in the package. They said I might be able to get an iso via rescue mode and go from there but they could only give me instructions on booting into rescue mode and mounting drives before it goes OOS. Looking for a headless iso/guide now..

Comment: So. Managed to give it once more try with OVH's installer. There's a checkbox that lets you "Install original kernel" in the setup. That worked out in the end.